# Perform action for duration of UILongPressGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, ios, uigesturerecognizer

I'd like to change the value of a `UISlider` continuously while a `UIButton` with a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` attached to it is being held. Right now I am only getting calls to my `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` delegate at touch down and touch up (begin/end).

Can I perform an action from `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` to `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` without tying up the UI? As expected, using a `while()` loop doesn't work.

Comment: In what way do you want to change the slider? Use a timer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working example of how you can accomplish what you're looking for. I tested it and works great.

All of this code goes in the *.m file. This is a very simple class that just extends `UIViewController`.

```
#import "TSViewController.h"

@interface TSViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *longPressTimer;

@end

@implementation TSViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressGesture:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
}

-(void)longPressGesture:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)longPress {

    // The long press gesture recognizer has been, well, recognized
    if (longPress.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

        if (self.longPressTimer) {
            [self.longPressTimer invalidate];
            self.longPressTimer = nil;
        }

        // Here you can fine-tune how often the timer will be fired. Right
        // now it's been fired every 0.5 seconds
        self.longPressTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(longPressTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }

    // Since a long press gesture is continuous you have to detect when it has ended
    // or when it has been cancelled
    if (longPress.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded || longPress.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled) {
        [self.longPressTimer invalidate];
        self.longPressTimer = nil;
    }
}

-(void)longPressTimer:(NSTimer*)timer {

    NSLog(@"User is long-pressing");
}

@end
```

Hope this helps!